# Нахождение в графе непересекающихся по вершинам и рёбрам кратчайших маршрутов

Tags: c, графы

Дан планарный, ненаправленный, не взвешенный, связный, ациклический граф. Есть start и end. Задача найти кратчайшие, не пересекающиеся по вершинам и рёбрам маршруты от начала до конца графа.

Посоветуйте, желательно с примерами, возможные реализации на СИ.

Comment: Если граф ненаправленный и ациклический .. то в нем не может быть более 1 маршрута .. не так ли?

Answer (score 1):

`Дан планарный, ненаправленный, не взвешенный, связный, ациклический граф`  - это **дерево**.

В дереве любой маршрут является кратчайшим. Найти маршрут между двумя узлами можно с помощью [поиска в ширину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)

*Понятия "начало и конец графа" сомнительные.*